# New Navigation sort bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Sorry if it's too early to report this, as the new navigation is available for a few minutes only, but filtering by tag and sorting doesn't seem to work together.

The following url / filter leading to the url

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?filter=no-answer&sort=votes
```

should show only questions tagged with JavaScript, sorted by votes and are unanswered. In fact, it shows answered questions, the rest fits the filter

[image]

Filtering without the tag criteria works perfectly fine though

Comment: For me, it seems to matter which order I do it in. I can filter with tags, but not if I changed the sort order first. If I filter, *then* change the sort order, it works fine...sometimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug with the no-answer filter. Should be fixed with the next build (build rev `2015.10.27.3790` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.27.2909` on sites).